# Как отследить html элемент, созданный динамически?

Tags: javascript, html

По нажатию на кнопку у меня в html-форме появляется новое поле для ввода. Я использую такой код:

```
        let newField = document.createElement('input');
        let formBlock = document.getElementById('mainForm');
        formBlock.appendChild(newField);
```

Однако как получить информацию с этого поля? Возможно есть способ добавить к нему ID?

Comment: *"Возможно есть способ добавить к нему ID?"* --- вопрос, вот у вас есть объект `let test = {}` вы можете туда добавить свойство и значение?

Comment: Не могу, тогда какая альтернатива?

Comment: `newField.setAttribute('id', 'id-here');`? Но лучше объясните конечную цель, потому что не факт что это Вам как-то поможет. Что за отслеживание и зачем?

Comment: *"Не могу"* - в смысле не можете? т.е. хотите сказать, что `test` только для чтение с момента создания?

Comment: newField.setAttribute('id', 'id-here'); - помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newField.setAttribute('id', 'id-here');
```

Первый параметр задаёт атрибут, а второй его значение.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Возможно не понял вопрос т.к не ясно для чего добавлять id.
А вот данные считываются с input , полем value.

```
let newField = document.createElement('input');
        let formBlock = document.getElementById('mainForm');
        
 
//добавляем клас css 
newField.classList.add("input");

//вставляем input в блок
formBlock.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", newField);

//в простом обработчике читаем input
formBlock.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(newField.value)
    
})
```